# swf plays locally but not online, how to?

Tags: html, object, flash

i have a swf: `Adjusting__Age.swf`. and what happens is that if i run it locale it works:

```
file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/test/Adjusting__Age.html
```

but if i sun it online or even in my localhost it doesnt appear:

```
http://localhost/test/Adjusting_Age.html
```

here is my code:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="512" height="384" id="training-video" align="middle">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
<param name="movie" value="videos/Adjusting__Age.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
<embed src="videos/Adjusting_Age.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="512" height="384" name="training-video" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
```

any ideas how to make this work?

thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Suggestion:1
First try to move your Adjusting_*Age.swf outside of videos directory and check manually. Such that both Adjusting*_Age.swf and Adjusting__Age.html are in the same directory (in this case : test) . So your code should look like.

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="512" height="384" id="training-video" align="middle">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
<param name="movie" value="Adjusting__Age.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
<embed src="Adjusting__Age.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="512" height="384" name="training-video" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
```

Or Maybe because of this filename error. Your embed src statement is showing Adjusting_Age.swf instead of Adjusting__Age.swf.

Code for your comment. Try this.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="author" content="Administrator">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="testing">

    </head>
  <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <center>
      <object
        classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
        codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0"

        width="560" height="410"
      >
        <param name="movie" value="Adjusting__Age.swf">
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF">

        <param name="quality" value="high">
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="samedomain">
        <embed
          type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
          pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash"

          width="560" height="410"
          src="Adjusting__Age.swf"
          bgcolor="#FFFFFF"
          quality="high"
          allowscriptaccess="samedomain"
        >
          <noembed>
          </noembed>
        </embed>
      </object>
    </center>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: nope, still in the same position. for some reason it doesn't want to play

Answer (score 1):

You should check that the IIS allow download of swf files - if not you need to add the correct MIME type.